# What location on a hypersphere maximizes the Manhattan distance of the radius?

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles, spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

In two dimension picture a unit circle. While the distance of the radius is constantly one, the Manhattan distance of the radius at zero degrees is equal to 1 while the Manhattan distance at 45 degrees is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\approx1.41$. Thus for a circle the difference between the minimum and maximum Manhattan distance is about 0.41. I am curious how this difference changes for higher dimensions. I know the minimum Manhattan distance will remain one, however, I am stumped how to find the maximum even for the sphere...I feel like it should just be a simple calculus exercise. I would appreciate any helping in setting up the solution for the sphere, and even better a general solution for a hypersphere!

I'm guessing that the difference continues to increase with dimension but asymptotically approaches some limit. Happy New Years!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know minimisation of multi-variable functions over given sets?

Your problem is essentially asking to maximise and minimise $f(x) = \sum_j x_j$ (the Manhattan distance, $x_j$ are the components of the vector $x$) on the set
$$ M := \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : x_j\geq 0 \text{ for all $j$ and } ||x||=1\} $$
It is enough to consider $M$ instead of the entire hypersphere by, well, *spherical* symmetry (pun intended).

This can happen either on the boundary (where, in this case, you will have the minimum) of the set or wherever $\nabla f(x) = \left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_n}\right)$ is orthogonal to $M$. Since $M$ is part of a sphere, this is equivalent to
$$\nabla f(x) = \lambda x$$
for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ (why?). This you can transform to a system of linear equations which you can solve. Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I think I can figure it out from here. Give me a bit to play around with it, and I’ll let you know!

Comment: Ok, I don't think I know quite enough to make complete use of this general solution. I tried to apply it to the 2D , since I know the solution and figured I could reverse engineer the gaps. But I am still a little stumped. If you could provide a little more guidance, maybe implement it for n=2 or 3, that would be amazing.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. I'm writing up my attempt at the solution now!

Answer (score 1):

While my solution is not as general or robust as whats outlined above; I used Tobius's answer as a blueprint for my solutions, and the results are kind of neat!

I implemented Tobius's approach in 3-dimensions because it helped me wrap my head around what the solution process looked like:

$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1+x_2+x_3$ subject to the constraint on set M that $g(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 1-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2=0$. So then if we have a solution of the form above it looks like $\nabla(f-\lambda g)=0$ Which gives us the following sets of equations
$$
1-2\lambda x_1 = 0
$$
$$
1-2\lambda x_2 = 0
$$
$$
1-2\lambda x_3 = 0
$$
$$
1-x_1^2-x_2^2-x_3^2 = 0
$$

Solving gives us $\lambda =\sqrt{3}/2$, and $x_1,x_2,x_3,=\sqrt{3}/3$ and thus the total manhatten distance is $\sqrt{3}$. In general this tells us that the maximal manhatten distance for the radius of a hypersphere of dimension n is just $\sqrt{n}$.

Thus the difference between the maximum and minimal manhatten distance of the radius of a hypersphere actually increase to infinity like $\sqrt{n}$ as dimensions increase to inifnity! Which I suppose isn't too surprising because with infinite dimensions the manhatten distance should be infinite for any non_zero radius...